# Tor+Filezilla(FTP): 'Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing'

Tags: networking, proxy, ftp, tor

I have a [domain](http://indiranagar.bangalore-property-buy.com/) on [NameCheap](http://namecheap.com/). I want to upload some files using Tor and the staff said I could use Filezilla.

I configured it by setting up a **FTP proxy** in `Edit-->Settings` and then added my account details into `File-->Site Manager`

I'm able to login but I can't retrieve the dir list:

```
Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9150...
Status: Connection with proxy established, performing handshake...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 17 of 50 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 04:47. Server port: 21.


Response:   230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 UNIX Type: L8


Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (104,219,248,93,105,217)
Command:    MLSD
Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9150...
Status: Connection with proxy established, performing handshake...
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

How do i fix this problem? (Output is snipped)